# React: Run on production without build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, iis

Before a deployment to production environment, people usually compile, build and compress react code. I know that makes file less-size and makes site faster.

**I am working for a fast iterative project now and some time I need to check the issue even on production server.** So, I assume if there is a solution to **run my development app just as local style.**

If I just use 'npm install', 'npm start' command on the production server, I think it should work. However, I am not sure if it is stable and I hope I can use normal deployment tool, such as IIS etc.

Here my question is: **is there any way to run development code on IIS?**

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: have you ever tried to deploy with a `npm run start:dev` script, it should be ok ?

Comment: @Pirs  thanks. it works. what I am concerned about is if the working site upon "npm run start:dev" is stable. could you please let me know any way to run dev code on IIS?

Comment: I dont know IIS at all, i work with cloud platform on linux only, i already deploy in dev mode, but it wasnt that kind of app with any need of compilation (like node+express app), i wonder if its possible with a reactJs+redux app, i dont think so cause the webpack... I cant help you more on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

http://dimaqq.github.io/kanji-sudoku/

It's ES6 + React.js all in a static HTML, all transpiled by Babel in the browser.

Nowadays ES6 is supported natively, and the above can be simplified.